# Current Location asked though not needed

Tags: google-maps, uiwebview, cllocationmanager

In an iPhone app I am opening a UIWebView object that I load with a URL like the following:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=36.294384,-85.749443&iwloc=A&hl=en
(an arbitrary location, somewhere on the planet)

The strange thing is that I get asked the permission to use the current location, when clearly I have no use for it. Why is that?

The fact is, the app works in any case, regardless of my answer to the question above.
But why the question in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the Google Maps website is using Safaris web API to ask for location. One can get a persons location using Safari and Google uses this functionality in their web version of maps.

edit: It's not currently possible to disable this prompt in the UIWebView (or any browser for that matter)

Comment: I see, thanks for this quick and clear answer. It makes the logic behind the issue easy to understand.
Nevertheless the message seen by the user is:
"My App" Would Like to Use Your Current Location
and of course I don't like it (the user won't either).
Is there a way to go around?

Comment: I think you mind find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261424/iphone-disable-uiwebview-from-prompting-to-enable-location-services

Comment: Thanks again, I had a quick look. It seems rocket science only for a small issue. As matter of fact, since I use Google map when the user has it, it does not even show up all the time. Anyway you helped me clarify the problem.